# Getting a valid value from StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> and a child StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get a specific icon to appear based on whether the user has taken the survey or not.

At the moment, I am using StreamBuilder to listen for a given value in a document, which returns the survey name. I then want to use the survey name in the next StreamBuilder, which will look in a given collection (which is made up of the survey name followed by _entrants - so, for example, Survey_entrants) for a completed survey document, which will have the title of the user's unique id (named userid).

The problem I have now is that whilst surveyName does return the name of the survey put in Cloud Firestore, and updates it when I change the value (I can see this by the commented-out return new Text('$surveyName'); command).

However, it does not seem to be passing that value into the next StreamBuilder - regardless of what I put in as the survey name, I get the check icon showing, suggesting (snapshot1.hasData) - even when that document does not exist.

I know the surveyName variable is working, but if I do snapshot1.toString() I get the error Snapshot(ConnectionState.active, Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', null). This must count has having data, hence showing the survey being taken. How do I correct this?

My code:

```
Positioned(
  right: 30,
  top: 20,
  child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection('Controller')
    .document('Current Survey')
    .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else {
        var sn = snapshot.data;
        surveyName = sn["cs"];
//      return new Text('$surveyName');
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
          .document(userid)
          .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot1) {
            if (!snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Icon(
                Foundation.burst_new,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            } else if (snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Icon(
                Foundation.check,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            } else {
              return Icon(
                MaterialIcons.error_outline,
                size: 48,
                color: Color(0xff303841),
              );
            }
          });
      }
    })),
```

Comment: My guess is that the child `StreamBuilder` doesn't rebuild when its parent does for optimization purposes, but by no means am I sure of this. You could pop your program in a debugger and see if this is the case.

Comment: If that is the case, you may be able to do a workaround with a `StatefulWidget` and `setState` or combine the streams together into one using one of the stream operations from RxDart (and consequently only have one `StreamBuilder` that will always rebuild then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was that Cloud Firestore returns a DocumentSnapshot even when there is nothing in the database to return. So, I changed `(snapshot1.hasData)` to `(snapshot1.data.exists)` and this works as expected - the icon changes based on the response.